# Issue in OnTouchListener for ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

I have set OnTouchListener to an image view. I want to do two different actions when user press down the image and also when press up the image. But always I am getting press down event as (ACTION_DOWN) but if i use button instead of ImageView then I can both ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP. But I have to use ImageView not Button. How to achieve ACTION_UP event in ImageView

```
prevImage.setOnTouchListener(this); // prevImage is an image View

@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.i("Wallpaper","...On touch ..." + arg1.getAction());
        if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //set img1 as imagesource 
        } else if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            //set img2 as imagesource and parse data from url
        }

        return false;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: some code on how you are testing events for image view would make us understand the problem better.

Comment: You can use ImageButton instead of ImageView or you can use Button and set the image as its background and achieve your aim. Hope this idea will help you.

Comment: Problem is that I have to use ImageView. and the image comes from server. If I use Button or ImageButton I am not getting the look and fill of an image.

Answer (score 7):

Don't know if this is too late or not.

You can do it by adding this to your imageView in your xml file

```
android:clickable="true"
```

and you can use if and else if like you already did there.

hope this helps.

Comment: also you can set onClickListener

Answer (score 1):

Please check if `ACTION_CANCEL` is fired instead of ACTION_UP. It may get fired instead of ACTION_UP when it comes to images.

[EDIT] Also, you have to return `true` if you intercept ACTION_DOWN event in order ACTION_UP to get fired.

Comment: Only ACTION_DOWN is fired no other event is getting fired

Comment: Are you returning `true` (you should) after intercepting ACTION_DOWN? Pasting some code may be useful...